# Performance test shows higher IOPS and throughput than whats actually provisioned on FSx for NetApps

Tags: amazon-web-services, netapp, amazon-fsx

I am using fio to run several performance tests on FSx for Netapps. FSx is configured with 1024 GiB of capacity and 128 MB/s throughputs. I am using automatic IOPS provisioning in this case IOPS count is (3 x 1024 = 3072).

But when i ran following test with [fio](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html), with following command,

```
sudo fio --name=write_throughput --directory=/fsx/ --size=1G --ramp_time=2s --ioengine=libaio --direct=1 --verify=0 --bs=32k --iodepth=64 --rw=write --group_reporting=1 --numjobs=1
```

and it gives 9k IOPS and 290MiB/s throughput which is way higher than the configuration.

[image]

What could be the reasons for the difference?

I have carried out similar tests against EFS and the results match the configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I missed the bursting throughput/iops with the FSx. File system with 128 Mb/s throughput capacity can burst up to 18,750 IOPS and 600 MB/s throughput.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fsx/latest/ONTAPGuide/performance.html